# Removing the first word from a sentence and store it c++

Tags: c++, string

I am reading from a file in C++, and I want to remove all but the first word and store it,

```
sentence = sentence.substr(sentence.find_first_of(" \t") + 
1);
```

this code remove the first word and keep the whole sentence , is there a way to store the removed word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of
take position of first match from find_first_of and then sentence start pos to position from find_first_of

`std::string w1 = sentence.substr(0, sentence.find_first_of(" \t"));`

Comment: Even that’s overkill. Use the file stream to read one word, which it does naturally, and then just stop reading.